# java.util.Date Strange issue showing future date in spring + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date, spring-mvc

## I am working on small project where I am using Spring mvc 4 +Hibernate.

In jsp file I am using jquery DatePicker

In  my entity when I use

```
@NotNull
    @Column(name = "schedule_date")
    private Date scheduleDate;
```

then in controller its giving value as

```
  scheduleDate = Mon Apr 11 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

which is future date (almost 5 month future date) but when I use

```
   @NotEmpty 
    @Column(name = "schedule_date")
    private String scheduleDate;
```

then in controller its giving value as

```
   scheduleDate = 16/11/2015
```

which is correct value.I don't know whats happening here

## How should I solve this issue As I want to Use Date instead of String as datatype for scheduleDate variable

Comment: This sounds like a formatting problem. How is your date stored in DB? What is the datatype?

Comment: as I am getting issue in controller I Have not yet written DAO

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for Your reply.I solved it.  now its giving correct date

```
Mon Nov 16 00:00:00 IST 2015
```

as compared to

```
Mon Apr 11 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

code i used in my controller is

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 dateFormat.setLenient(false);
 webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see that value for Date type, it is the `toString` representation.

The problem you have is that datePicker is JavaScript and need a string representation of a date.

So, don't expose directly the date attribute from model to view, instead use a date formatter to pass the date.

Comment: I am new to Spring If you have any example then let me know.I am not getting what you are trying to say :)  One more thing to Mention Why its showing Future date when using Date as datatype